# How do I step down my voltage and up my current for a tethered drone

Tags: power-supply, buck

I'm fairly new to this platform but would like your advice on one of the projects that I'm working on.

I am currently working on adding a tethering system to the DJI S1000+ spreading wings octocopter to allow for 'unlimited flight time.'  I am planning on using a generator to supply AC current, a power supply to step the voltage down and switch to DC and then make use of DC-DC buck converters to step the voltage down and up the current.

However, I'm running into a lot of problems and I can't seem to  find the correct buck converters and power supply. The motors draw a lot of current - about 40A.

Comment: Hi! You need to ask a precise question that we can answer. What's that question here?

Comment: What is the correct buck converter that you can't find?

Comment: DJI's website says this thing is normally powered from a 6S LiPo. Taking 4V per LiPo makes 24V. A rather common voltage. Now we know the required output voltage, what is your planned input voltage range?

Comment: Weigh the power supply and buck to 24V 40A. Weigh 1m of each : 24V 40A cable, 240V 4A cable, optionally 115V 8A cable if you're in 115V-land. Combine this information with the excess lift of your drone to decide whether you want the AC supply on the ground and 40A cable to the drone, or 4A cable to a 240V supply on the drone. Which solution allows greater height? Does either allow the height you are looking for?